# Where Can I find Data on African Startups?

Tags: data-request, africa

AngelList data is very outdated. I want to create a CrunchBase-like  database of African Startups.

Things like this would help:
 - Size
 - Location (City, Country)
 - Website
 - Funding
 - Social Media
etc

Answer (score 1):

You can search for startups in [crunchbase](https://www.crunchbase.com) using "Africa" in Location filtre.